# Retrieving normal after rotating an instance model in HLSL

Tags: model, xna, hlsl, normals, geometry-instancing

I begin to use the "instancied model" technique to draw my scene and I've got a problem with normal's vertex

I give to HLSL the MATRIX ( rotation / scale / position ) to draw each instance of model but I can't obtain the good normal after rotate them.

The 3D computation of my model works fine after MATRIX apply , but the light is really strange depending of normal orientation.

```
struct InstancingVSinput
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION0;
    float4 Norm : NORMAL0;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct InstancingVSoutput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float3 Norm : NORMAL0;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

    InstancingVSoutput InstancingVS(InstancingVSinput input, 
                                    float4 InstPos : POSITION1, float4 InstTexCoord : TEXCOORD1,
                                    float4 Mat1 : POSITION2, float4 Mat2 : POSITION3, float4 Mat3 : POSITION4, float4 Mat4 : POSITION5)
    {
        InstancingVSoutput output;

        float4x4 O = float4x4(Mat1, Mat2, Mat3, Mat4);

        float4 pos = mul(input.Position,xWorld);
        pos = mul(input.Position, O);
        pos = InstPos + pos;

        O = transpose(O);

        float3 norm = normalize((float3)input.Norm);
        norm = mul(norm, (float3x3)O);

        pos = mul(pos, WVP);

        output.Position = pos;
        output.Norm = norm;

        output.TexCoord = float2((input.TexCoord.x / 2.0f) + (1.0f / 2.0f * InstTexCoord.x),
                                 (input.TexCoord.y / 2.0f) + (1.0f / 2.0f * InstTexCoord.y));
        return output;
    }

    float4 InstancingPS(InstancingVSoutput input) : COLOR0
    {
        float4 C = tex2D(TextureSampler, input.TexCoord);
        float3 N = input.Norm;
        C.rgb *= dot(float3(0, -1, -1), N);
        return C;
    }
```

Should you suggest me a correct way to retrieve my normal after rotation ?

Thanx

Chris

Answer (score 0):

If your instance matrix contains any scaling, you need to normalize the normals *after* the multiplication. Additionally, if the scaling is not uniform, you must multiply the input normals by the [inverse transpose](https://web.archive.org/web/20120228095346/http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tut09%20Normal%20Transformation.html) of the matrix. Currently you are only applying the transpose, but not the inverse.

Calculating the inverse of a matrix is an expensive operation, though, so consider precomputing it outside the shader.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I'm going to try ... and will see

Comment: Sorry but after try , it doesn't work ... 
It seems like each instance draws well rotated by geometry but faces are  lighted as they would not be rotated

Answer (score 0):

Here are the following lines I've modify to express your solution :

1 - Prepare the instances properties , just add a new one for Inverse Transpose Matrix ( precomputedted )

```
        Matrix MatRot = Matrix.CreateRotationX(3 - rnd.Next(6)) * 
                        Matrix.CreateRotationY(3 - rnd.Next(6)) * 
                        Matrix.CreateRotationZ(3 - rnd.Next(6));
        instances[i].Geometry = Matrix.CreateScale(0.5f + rnd.Next(2)) * MatRot;
        instances[i].Inverse = Matrix.Transpose(Matrix.Invert(MatRot));
```

2 - The shader recept this new matrix and use it on the each model's normal

```
float4x4 WVP;
float4x4 WV;
float4x4 xLightView;
float4x4 xLightProj;
float4x4 xWorld;

texture cubeTexture;
sampler TextureSampler = sampler_state
{
    texture = <cubeTexture>;
    mipfilter = LINEAR;
    minfilter = LINEAR;
    magfilter = LINEAR;
};

struct InstancingVSinput
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Norm : NORMAL0;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct InstancingVSoutput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float4 Norm : NORMAL0;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

InstancingVSoutput InstancingVS(InstancingVSinput input, 
                                float4 InstPos : POSITION1, float4 InstTexCoord : TEXCOORD1,
                                float4 Mat1 : POSITION2, float4 Mat2 : POSITION3, float4 Mat3 : POSITION4, float4 Mat4 : POSITION5,
                                float4 Mat5 : POSITION6, float4 Mat6 : POSITION7, float4 Mat7 : POSITION8, float4 Mat8 : POSITION9)
{
    InstancingVSoutput output;

    float4x4 O = float4x4(Mat1, Mat2, Mat3, Mat4);
    float4x4 I = float4x4(Mat5, Mat6, Mat7, Mat8);

    float4 pos = mul(input.Position,xWorld);
    pos = mul(input.Position, O);
    pos = InstPos + pos;

    pos = mul(pos, WVP);
    output.Position = pos;

    output.Norm = normalize(mul(input.Norm,I));

    output.TexCoord = float2((input.TexCoord.x / 2.0f) + (1.0f / 2.0f * InstTexCoord.x),
                             (input.TexCoord.y / 2.0f) + (1.0f / 2.0f * InstTexCoord.y));

    return output;
}

float4 InstancingPS(InstancingVSoutput input) : COLOR0
{
    float4 C = tex2D(TextureSampler, input.TexCoord);

    C.rgb *= dot(input.Norm , normalize(float3(0, -1, -1)));
    return C;
}

technique Instancing
{
    pass Pass0
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_5_0 InstancingVS();
        PixelShader = compile ps_5_0 InstancingPS();
    }
}
```

An idea ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see , my faces have not a good ligh exposition depending of the normal

[Click to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Sj0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved , it's OK. In fact , HLSL code was good ... but the problem was persisting because of a bad computation of vertex normals. Now I have good faces with good light direction.